# Error message while Sharing web url in a browser via whatsapp and whatsapp is not installed in the particular device

Tags: whatsapp, socialshare

I am developing social sharing plugin where I want to share my web application url in a browser using whatsapp for mobile device. I am using below code:
"whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!"

Using above code, when I try to share without whatsapp installed in the device, it opens up a blank page.

If the user is sharing it via whatsapp and the device doesn't have whatsapp then how can we notify the user that whatsapp is not installed or redirect user to appstore or playstore to install whatsapp?

Comment: Same problem here, I have on mobile a dirty error message. Have ou find a way to personalize it ? Or any other solution ?